# Pull requests overriding earlier commits

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I am new to Git so bear with me.

I have a Git repository (on GitHub) and I have lots of coders who are inexperienced with Git. When I hire them, I ask them to make a pull request towards my repository so I can review their changes before I merge. At the moment my biggest problem is that often I merge changes into my repository after they fork it, but before they make their pull request, meaning that merging their pull request overrides an earlier commit.

Is there a way for me to ensure that this will not happen apart from telling them to avoid the problem?

Comment: I see you removed the accepted answer tick. Is there any other information I can add to my answer?

Comment: @vonc I am really looking for a solution to avoid the whole problem, while your answer explains what is causing it and what I should do after the problem has arisen.

Answer (score 2):

The way to ensure that this will not happen is to reject any commit which cannot be applied in a fast-forward manner.
But nothing prevent a user to submit a pull-request without first updating his/her own fork.

A correct pull request should be applied in a fast-forward manner, which means a contributor should first rebase his/her work on top of the latest commit of the destination repo (ie git pull --rebase), *before* making the pull request.

In other words, they should first integrate your other changes you have merged in their own local repo, test that their contribution is still working, *before* the pull request.
If they do that, there won't be any issue with overriding  earlier commits.
If there is, you simply reject the pull request, asking the contributor to rebase the local repo first.

Answer (score 1):

**The hard way**: Ask them to create a (local) branch before merge.

**The easy way**: Let's forget "how to avoid the problem", tell them how to fix it. In git, we have `git reflog` that can rollback (almost) any changes.

P.S. Merging don't "override" an earlier commit. You can use `git log ; git reset` to fix (most) of it even if you don't have reflog.

Comment: My problem is mostly that I have to review their commits very carefully, to see whether they some of the earlier commits are lost if I merge their pull request automatically. To be frank I do not understand anything of your answer. But I will review the commands you refer to (especially reflog) to see if I can understand your answer better when I have more knowledge of Git.