# Should I ask the contributor to rebase her/his repository before pull request?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I use the Integration-Manager Workflow as it is specified in git documentation:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

But I am getting some problems in the following scenario:

- The contributor pull changes from the main repository then create a new branch to work on a new issue
- The main repository advance in commits, while the contributors branch is getting too old...
- The contributor finish the issue, then send me a pull request to integrate his/her branch to main repository, but he/she dont rebase the branch before.

Now I have problems to merge it, because it is too old compared to the main repository, so should I ask the contributor to rebase her/his repository before pull request? or Should I merge it?

In git docs step 5, there is:
"The maintainer adds the contributor’s repo as a remote and merges locally."

but in questions like: [Pull requests overriding earlier commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445392/pull-requests-overriding-earlier-commits)

they says that is correct to ask the contributors to rebase first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, I'd ask them to rebase. It takes work away from you, and they are more easily able to solve conflicts since they know their code. They might also want to run the test suite and so on.

Comment: I totally agree with you! thank you. but why git docs says  "The maintainer adds the contributor’s repo as a remote and **merges locally**."? is the doc 'teaching' a wrong workflow?

Comment: `git` does not come with "a" workflow. The page you liked says that it contains "common paradigms" and tells you to "mix and match". So you can do whatever you like, and if in doubt it's always good for the contributor to do as much work and make the effort for the maintainer as small as possible, especially in larger projects (where the maintainer might have his hands full anyways); but also in small projects, out of courtesy. So, if you as maintainer have no trouble doing the rebase yourself (maybe it runs without conflicts and the test suite stays green), go ahead; otherwise let them do it.

Comment: thank you, it's clear now. Indeed, it's better let them do it.